# MATLAB - Permute columns of a matrix given a matrix of indices

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

Given a matrix X, I want to set the k smallest elements of each column to zero. For a vector x, I do the following:

```
[~, ind] = sort(x)
x(ind(1:k)) = 0
```

Now, for a matrix X, this does not work:

```
[~, IND] = sort(X)
X(IND(1:k)) = 0
```

Just sets the k smallest element of the first column to 0. How do I index it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution Code:** One approach with [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) (to get column-wise sorted indices) & then [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) (to get linear sorted indices) -

```
%// Get 2D array of column-sorted indices for input X
[~,sorted_idx] = sort(X,1)

%// Get linear indices for the first k rows of sorted indices
lin_idx = bsxfun(@plus,sorted_idx(1:k,:),[0:size(X,2)-1]*size(X,1))

%// Use those indices to set them in X as zeros
X(lin_idx) = 0;
```

**Sample run**

1) Inputs:

```
X =
    61    67    86    54    49    40    13
    48    91    28    70    34    98    87
    79     7    27    86    71    58    52
    16    10    45    60    79     4     3
    56    36    49    50    31    48    87
k =
     3
```

2) Sorted indices:

```
>> [~,sorted_idx] = sort(X,1)
sorted_idx =
     2     3     2     1     1     1     1
     4     4     3     4     2     4     3
     5     5     4     5     5     5     4
     1     1     5     2     3     3     2
     3     2     1     3     4     2     5
```

3) Select only the first k indices from each column:

```
>> sorted_idx(1:k,:)
ans =
     4     3     3     5     5     4     4
     2     4     2     1     2     1     1
     5     5     4     4     1     5     3
```

4) We need to convert those column-wise indices to linear indices corresponding to the 2D array, `X`. So, following the column-major indexing used in MATLAB, the first column stays as it is, the second column must have the offset of the `number of rows in X` added, the third column would have `2*number of rows in X` added and so on until all columns are covered.

To put it mathematically, we would have `[0  5 10 15 20 25 30]`, i.e. `[0:6]*5` , i.e. to put as a generic case `[0:size(X,2)-1]*size(X,1)`, added to `sorted_idx(1:k,:)`. Since we need to do this for every row of `sorted_idx(1:k,:)`, we can use the automatic expansion and summation (with `@plus`) with `bsxfun`. Please note that this would be done in a vectorized manner. Thus, here the expansion of `[0:size(X,2)-1]*size(X,1)` would take place along the rows and then the elementwise summations with `sorted_idx(1:k,:)` using `@plus` would be performed. So, we would have the much needed linear indices like so -

```
>> lin_idx = bsxfun(@plus,sorted_idx(1:k,:),[0:size(X,2)-1]*size(X,1))
lin_idx =
     4     8    13    20    25    29    34
     2     9    12    16    22    26    31
     5    10    14    19    21    30    33
```

5) Finally, we use these indices to selectively set zeros in `X` with `X(lin_idx) = 0`.

Comment: If you have time, could you explain what bsxfun exactly does? That would greatly improve this answer with such an elegant solution.

Comment: @BananaCode Added some explanation in it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`quantile`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/quantile.html) (Statistics Toolbox):

```
X = X .* bsxfun(@ge, X, quantile(X, k/size(X,1)));
```

**How it works**:

1. `quantile(X, k/size(X,1))` gives, for each column, a number (quantile) such that a fraction `k/size(X,1))` of the entries in that column are less than that number. This means that, in each, column, exactly `k` entries are less than the column quantile.
2. Comparing each column with the corresponding quantile (`bsxfun(@ge, ...)`) gives a matrix that contains `0` for entries less than the quantile, and `1` otherwise.
3. Element-wise multiplication of `A` by the result of 2 makes the desired values of `A` equal to `0`.

**Example**:

```
>> X = rand(5,3)
X =
   0.088188645571510   0.907109055220371   0.805984932289666
   0.683710335821638   0.860456667336885   0.868488116302772
   0.120400876857723   0.338451384118250   0.669646599875533
   0.010699003144174   0.027158829325862   0.807778862315076
   0.557268230074914   0.800859355130033   0.897498282302820
>> k=2;
>> X = X.*bsxfun(@ge, X, quantile(X,k/size(X,1)))
X =
                   0   0.907109055220371                   0
   0.683710335821638   0.860456667336885   0.868488116302772
   0.120400876857723                   0                   0
                   0                   0   0.807778862315076
   0.557268230074914   0.800859355130033   0.897498282302820
```

Comment: This answer looks very interesting. Explaining exactly how it works would greatly aid in its usefulness.